# Reusable factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have such a simple code, where I want to have a reusable `factory` that I can use across multiple `ng-app`.

```
  var app1 = angular.module("xxx", [])
      .factory("yyy", function () {
          console.log("yyy");
      });


  var app = angular
    .module("Operations", ["ngRoute", "ui.bootstrap", "cgBusy", "xxx"])
    .config(carsAppConfig)
    .constant("Events", events)
    .run(function ($rootScope){
      $rootScope.handleErrors = handleErrors;
    });

  carsAppConfig.$inject = ["$httpProvider", "$locationProvider", "$routeProvider", "yyy"];

  function carsAppConfig($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $routeProvider, yyy) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function (responseData) {
      convertDateStringsToDates(responseData);
      return responseData;
    });
```

but it complains it cannot create the Operations module because it cannot find the `yyy` dependency.

Using `angular 1.10.2`. 
Did anything changed in the angular that prohibits such constructions?

Thx

Comment: Im a little confused by your code here... Are you attempting to create two separate modules? You first declared your angular module as 'xxx' and then further down you declare another module 'Operations'.

Comment: You can't inject services into config, only providers

Comment: oh snap, thx EP. How would I then create a reusable httpInterceptor that I can use across modules?

Comment: ok, problem solved, after all, that service method can be just a regular JS function that returns an object with needed properties. All good now :)